# Using App name with Django.contrib.auth views

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am creating a user change password page. However, I keep encountering a `NoReverseMatch` error which I suspect is due to my `app name` but I am not able to resolve it even after spending hours googling for a solution.

My urls.py file:

```
from os import name
from django.urls import path
from account import views


from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views     # Import Django built-in authentication views



app_name    = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', views.test_login, name='test'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),

]
```

My settings.py:

```
# Login Logic
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL      = 'account:test'    # Tells Django which URL to redirect user to after a successful login if no next parameter is present in the request
LOGIN_URL               = 'account:login'        # The URL to redirect the user to log in - based on the name in the urls.py
LOGOUT_URL              = 'account:logout'       # The URL to redirect the user to log out - based on the name in the urls.py
```

my html file

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{# This is the template to allow user to change their password #}

{% block title %}Change Your Password{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                <form action="{% url 'account:password_change_done' %}" class="form-signin" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}

                    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center">Change your password</h1>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="old_password">Old Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" required id="id_old_password" name="old_password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Old Password" autofocus>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new_password1">New Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" required id="id_new_password1" name="new_password1" autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="New Password">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new_password2">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" required id="id_new_password2" name="new_password2" autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    </div>

                    <small class="form-text text-muted">
                        {% if form.new_password1.help_text %}
                            {{ form.new_password1.help_text|safe }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </small>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>

                {% if form.errors %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Much help is appreciated.

Have added in the html file for referece

Comment: Is this your root urls file? You cannot set app_name if it is

Comment: Hi lain, if I get what you mean - root urls file as in the default url file that comes with django-admin startproject then No. This urls.py is from an app I created called 'account'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "NoReverseMatch" error means , Django is not being able to process and see the exact url being passed.
Including the "app_name" has said by most Django devs makes the code neat and easy to streamline to as to which url you want and most importantly helps to avoid duplicating urls..

An instance will be having this url path of "home" in your app accounts and also having that same path "home" in some other app, the use of specifying the app_name will help Django , include the urls to their respective apps so you know which requires which .

Your urls are correct to me and since it's a NoReverseMatch error, it will have to be your at your html or view or anywhere where you are calling a url.

Try including the app name in either your html and view on where you are calling the url..
Something like this

{% app_name:name_url %}
And same to the view app_name:name_url

Always make sure there is semi-colon between the app_name and the url ... As it will help you tell Django as to which url from which app!!

Comment: Hi Harrison, thank you so much!

I have added in the {% url 'account:password_change_done; %} in my html file. The URL is directed correctly but I got a HTTP error 405.

To resolve this, I need to refresh the page again. 

Any idea why it is like this and how I can resolve this error? I have added my html code to the original question.

Comment: Ok regarding the error, a 405 means a not allowed. That happens when your server knows of the method used but doesn't allow that probably due to a change in error or some other change.. I can't tell for sure what it is , but again you said it happened in a way you had to refresh the page, this means Django is actually serving the post method at the "back" of the backend if that makes sense but what Django sees at the forefront is the get method .. In essence it appears like Django is sending a get method , but at the back of the backend , it actually serves the post method